# Using Maven to create "runnable WAR"

Tags: java, maven, jetty

Okay, I'm trying to create a war file that is runnable from the command line using Maven.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</warName>
        <warSourceDirectory>src\main\java\META-INF\webapp\WEB-INF</warSourceDirectory>
        <webXml>src\main\java\META-INF\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>classes\ReportToolRunner</mainClass>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run the compiled war file, I get "Error: Could not find or load main class classes\ReportToolRunner", I've tried all manner of different paths for the <\mainClass> tag.

I don't want to run the war using tomcat or anything like that, I just want to be able to run it like:

```
java -jar reportTool.war
```

I'm using Jetty for my web server.

Comment: WAR files are for web applications intended to be deployed in a container (like Tomcat or Jetty) and are designed with a different lifecycle than a main driving method. What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Within the project, I have created a webservice, using Jetty as the web server. It all runs fine in the IDE, but when I tried building a *jar* file, I had issues with the fact that it didn't include the "META-INF" directory, Google told me that you need war files for such things, so that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, if you embed a servlet container like Jetty:
[Embedded Jetty Executable War](http://uguptablog.blogspot.de/2012/09/embedded-jetty-executable-war-with.html).

**Note:** A runnable war is not very common. (For example Jenkins did this - It allows the user to decide whether to run the application standealone - maybe for some product evaluation, where no further infrastructure should be installed - or to deploy it on a (shared) servlet container, which gets managed and monitored)

**Solution:**
The following steps are necessary and can be achieved with standard Maven plugins:

1. Write a Main class, that starts the Jetty server and adds the webapp context
2. At prepare-package phase move the Main class and all classes used for the server start from ${project.build.directory}/classes/ to the target war directory to fulfill the jar layout (in a war file the classes are in a "classes" folder, but in a jar file the classes are in the root folder)

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>classes-copy</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
          <move todir="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/">
            <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes/">
              <include name="your.package.Main.class" />
            </fileset>
          </move>
        </tasks>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

3. Unpackage all dependencies, which are necessary for the Jetty server startup, so those classes are a part of your executable war. (You can skip this, but then those dependencies must be available on the classpath, when the war is executed as jar: java -cp <your classpath> -jar <your war>. (Please note: The dependency list, depends on your Jetty server implementation)

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jetty-classpath</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <includeGroupIds>org.eclipse.jetty,javax.servlet</includeGroupIds>
        <outputDirectory>
          ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}
        </outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

4. Specify the main class within the manifest, so that the war file can be executed as a jar. (Please note: I also specified the war name. This name is used in the previous plugin configurations as part of the "move todir" and the "outputDirectory")

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <warName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</warName>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>your.package.Main</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-war</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>war</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is the server code (Jetty version 8.1.0.v20120127) I used. It configures a new Jetty server and adds a webapp context (see last code snippet) - if configured correctly the server can be started and stopped with server.start() / server.stop():

```java
// Create connector
SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();
connector.setMaxIdleTime(1000 * 60 * 60);
connector.setSoLingerTime(-1);
connector.setPort(8080);

// Create handler collection
ContextHandlerCollection contextHandlerCollection = new ContextHandlerCollection();
HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contextHandlerCollection });

// Add webapp context
context.setServer(server);
contextHandlerCollection.addHandler(context);

server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });
server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
```

And finally the webapp context code:

```java
public class ServerContextImpl extends WebAppContext {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ServerContextImpl.class);

  protected static final String[] JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES;

  static {
    JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES = new String[7];
    JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES[0] = "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration";
    JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES[1] = "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration";
    JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES[2] = "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration";
    JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES[3] = "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration";
    JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES[4] = "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration";
    JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES[5] = "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration";
    JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES[6] = "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration";
  }

  ServerContextImpl() {
    setConfigurationClasses(JETTY_PLUS_CONFIGURATION_CLASSES);
    setContextPath("/");
    setWar(getWarLocation());
  }

  /**
   * Returns the location of the war (a trick, which is necessary for executable
   * wars please see: <a target="_blank" href=
   * "http://uguptablog.blogspot.de/2012/09/embedded-jetty-executable-war-with.html"
   * >Embedded Jetty with executable WAR</a>).
   * 
   * @return The war location.
   */
  protected String getWarLocation() {
    ProtectionDomain protectionDomain = ServerImpl.class.getProtectionDomain();
    URL location = protectionDomain.getCodeSource().getLocation();
    return location.toExternalForm();
  }
}
```

Please note the getWarLocation() method. It uses the packaged war itself as location.

Comment: What if I'm dependent on other classes within the war? Not just external jars? I've got it all rigged up so that all the correct groupIDs are included, and the main class is pointed to, however I'm now getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: files/CacheFileManager" <- That being a class within the war file. How do I point it to look into the lib directory?

Comment: Is the cache file manager used for the startup or within your web application? If it is used for the server start up it mus be moved to the root (see step 2). If the class is from a dependency, unpackage the dependeny as well (see step 3) - you can check the war file, that all necessary classes are there. All other classes and libs required for the webapp will be loaded by Jetty from WEB-INF/classes/* and WEB-INF/lib/*

Comment: For example my war file looks like this: Under root there my server start up classes /de/..., the Jetty classes /org/eclipse/eclipse/jetty/* and the servlet api classes /javax/servlet/*. Under WEB-INF/classes there are my webapp specific servlets, rest resources etc. and under WEB-INF/lib the webapp specific libraries (Maven dependencies) like jersey, gson and commons-io. I hope this helps and makes it clear.

Comment: This does not work, I get `Could not find or load main class` and indeed the created war doesn't have the `classes` directory where it could find it.

Comment: can you have a look at step 2 and step 4 again. your main class, which starts the Jetty server must be copied to classes/ (step 2) and be specified within the manifest (step 4)

Comment: For reference, running Jenkins self-contained as `java -jar jenkins.war` is its normal mode; loading it into a separate servlet container is rare.

Answer (score 4):

I did some research into this recently, and found flaws with most approaches (either to slow to build (shade, assembly, jar-with-dependencies)), too verbose, or not self-contained.

I found that a great way of doing this, which gave the best result (fast build, self-contained, simple setup) was the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. It's as simple as this:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
  <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.MyMainClass</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

With some simple tweaks it can even build a war that can be deployed, as well as executed.

This plugin can be used even though your project doesn't use Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not right using `<mainClass>`

From: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

> If you want to create an executable jar file, you need to configure
>   Maven Archiver accordingly. You need to tell it which main class to
>   use. This is done with the  configuration element. Here is
>   a sample pom.xml configured to add the classpath and use the class
>   fully.qualified.MainClass as the main class:

```
 <project>   ...   <build>
     <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         ...
         <configuration>
           <archive>
             <manifest>
               <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
               <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
             </manifest>
           </archive>
         </configuration>
         ...
       </plugin>
     </plugins>   </build>   ...   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
       <version>2.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
       <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
       <version>1.1</version>
     </dependency>   </dependencies>   ... </project>
```

> The manifest produced using the above configuration would look like
>   this:
>
> Manifest-Version: 1.0 Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver Created-By:
>   Apache Maven ${maven.version} Built-By: ${user.name} Build-Jdk:
>   ${java.version} Main-Class: fully.qualified.MainClass Class-Path:
>   plexus-utils-1.1.jar commons-lang-2.1.jar