# Separate Spring Boot module in multi-module webapp?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, multi-module

Is there a way to separate the creation of an executable war of webapp in a multi-module Maven project? Ie I would like to have a structure of

parent

- module 1 (webapp, produces a normal war)
- module 2 (spring boot, produces an executable war of module 1 with bundled Tomcat)
- module 3 (documentation for the product)
- module 4 (assembly module which creates an distribution package)

EDIT: If it is possible, what should I put in module 2's pom.xml? I know how to do it inside the same project/module which produces the war in the first place (there's a ton of examples of this on the net), but I have not been able to figure out whether it possible to keep it separate.

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061346/using-maven-to-create-runnable-war

Comment: @Aman This does not work cause the question is about: Spring boot...

Comment: what matters is what build system you are using, it is not a problem whether it is spring-boot or any other. For instance, if you use maven, you can create multi module project(pom) which finally resolves to a war.